# How to customize Date Picker via simple css?

Tags: html, css, datepicker, saas

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

[image]

My code is below

HTML

```
<input
 type="date"
>
```

CSS

```
input {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

**html file**

```
<div id="datepicker-container" class="datepicker-container">
  <span class="outline-element-container"> <input id="datepicker-input" type="text" class="openemr-datepicker input-textbox outline-element incorrect" placeholder="Type Name" objtype="7" name="action_element" objindex=""  aria-label="Select Date"> <span class="correct-incorrect-icon"> </span></span>
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>

<div class="datepicker-container openemr-calendar" id="datepicker-div" ></div>
```

**css file**

```
/* datepicker css */

.ui-datepicker {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.ui-datepicker {
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-color: #c9f0f5 !important;
}

.ui-datepicker {
    width: 256px;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker {
    width: 191px;
}

.ui-datepicker table {
    width: 256px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker table {
    width: 191px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
    background-color: #3e9aba !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-header {
    background-color: #e6f7f9 !important;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #c9f0f5;
    border-style: solid;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
    line-height: 35px !important;
    margin: 0 10px !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-title {
    line-height: 20px !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev span {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker-next span {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAMCAYAAACulacQAAAAUklEQVQYlXWPwQnAMAwDj9IBOlpH8CjdJLNksuujFIJjC/w6WUioFBcqJ7sGEAD5Y/hpqLRghRv4YQlUjqXI3Kql2MixraGbEhVcDXcFUR/1egEHNuTBpFW0NgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    width: 7px !important;
    margin: 14px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-prev {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAOCAYAAAD9lDaoAAAAuUlEQVQokXXRsUtCYRAA8J8pDQ1CVIgIgtBU2NDiZIuDS4uLf6WDS1O0tLREEE8icBNKS3lTs8/B78XHw3dwcHA/juOuqjzucYJVrQQMcYctvo4OgEFIeMK6iPphCjzjEWLUC3vACx7yRo5uMUIFr5gii1EL41AvMIkBVPGH04DrSLEsIvjEOZq4wi9+iijDR0ANXOMbmxjlcIY2LtANO6YxymGCDs5wg/ciYv+KBJeY4+2A+Y9j4Y47RtUkrNXeDxUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    width: 9px !important;
    margin: 5px !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAMCAYAAABfnvydAAAAVUlEQVQYlXWQ0Q3AIAhEL07gKI7kKN2kI3Wk1w9to3KQEELucQEECOizhhTQGHFnwOdgobWx0GkZILfYBhXl0STVbPoBarbkL7ozN/F8VBBXh8uJgF5r2hrI4GHUkAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    width: 8px !important;
    margin: 14px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-next {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAOCAYAAAASVl2WAAAAtElEQVQYlXXQsUpCcRQH4I97EQyHa1pgIEE0hBGYL+BjNLRFjxXh4rM4F21BS4S4FAgqQioOngt/RM/6+zi/w4EanlA4MDkecYsO3vG/D8a4Rx03eMMqBQt8oodTXAdalwBm+IpNDVxG3aYEMMU3ujjDBT5SAH9R2cE58mwPFOgneJSCGp7RjLoXTEtQjbCFOV7xCxkqdp9sYxnhpFyb4QFXdh8c4Cc9Ko++OwzjFwfn5FiwBVeuI/K2UCkSAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    width: 8px !important;
    margin: 5px;
}

.ui-datepicker-month {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #3985a0;
    width: 110px !important;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    border: none !important;
    margin-right: 17px !important;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-month {
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.87);
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    transform: scaleX(1.0029)
}

.ui-datepicker-year {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #3985a0;
    width: 61px !important;
    height: 22px;
    border: none !important;
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-year {
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.87);
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    transform: scaleX(1.0029)
}

.ui-datepicker-month option,
.ui-datepicker-year option {
    color: #3985a0 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.ui-datepicker-month option[selected],
.ui-datepicker-year option[selected] {
    background-color: #e5edf0 !important;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-state-hover {
    /*background: none !important;*/
    border: 0 !important;
}

.ui-datepicker td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-state-default {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #edebeb !important;
/*     background: white !important; */
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    margin: 7px 0 0 4px;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight{
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #cff3f8 !important;
    color: #3e9aba !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-state-default {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker td {
    width: 33px;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker td {
    width: 26px;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-state-default {
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover {
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #cff3f8 !important;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-state-active {
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #cff3f8 !important;
    color: #3e9aba !important;
} 

.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr th {
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #549fa8;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0.45em 0.3em !important;
    /*   width: 15px !important; */
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr th {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.ui-datepicker-close {
    display: none;
}

.ui-datepicker thead {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker thead {
    background: none;
}

.ui-state-default.ui-datepicker-current {
    float: none !important;
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane.ui-widget-content {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3e9aba;
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-year {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-month {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-state-default {
    border: 0 !important;
}

.openemr-calendar .ui-datepicker-month {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

**js file**

```
$( "#datepicker-input" ).datepicker({
  // altField: "#datepicker-input",
  // altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
   dayNamesMin : [ "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S" ],
  // defaultDate: +1,
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAATCAYAAAB2pebxAAABGUlEQVQ4jc2UP06EQBjFfyCN3ZR2yxHwBGBCYUIhN1hqGrWj03KsiM3Y7p7AI8CeQI/ATbBgiE+gMlvsS8jM+97jy5s/mQCFszFQAQN1c2AJZzMgA3rqpgcYx5FQDAb4Ah6AFmdfNxp0QAp0OJvMUii2BDDUzS3w7s2KOcGd5+UsRDhbAo+AWfyU4GwnPAYG4XucTYOPt1PkG2SsYTbq2iT2X3ZFkVeeTChyA9wDN5uNi/x62TzaMD5t1DTdy7rsbPfnJNan0i24ejOcHUPOgLM0CSTuyY+pzAH2wFG46jugupw9mZczSORl/BZ4Fq56ArTzPYn5vUA6h/XNVX03DZe0J59Maxsk7iCeBPgWrroB4sA/LiX/R/8DOHhi5y8Apx4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
  buttonText: "Pick Date",
  showOn: "button",
});

// debugger;
$( "#datepicker-div" ).datepicker({
  // altField: "#datepicker-input",
  // altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  // hideIfNoPrevNext = true,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
   dayNamesMin : [ "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S" ],
  // defaultDate: +1,
});
```

Comment: this is not a solution, this is a workaround using JQuery